# How to wait for didUpdateLocation method to be called before calling another method?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, cllocationmanager

I am working on an app where I want to store the user's current location when the user signs up.

So, as soon as the user clicks the signup button the locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() is called and then the signup operation is performed.

However, even before the didUpdateLocations delegate method returns a co-ordinate the signup method is triggered and hence the user's location is stored as nil in the database.

Trying to call the signup method inside the didUpdateLocations is a mess since, this delegate is called multiple times.

```
    func signup() { 
        self.getLocation()
        let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude:locationLat, longitude:locationLon)
        ...
        newUser[PF_USER_LOCATION] = point
        newUser.signUpInBackground(block: { (succeed, error) -> Void in

            if let errorInSignup = error {
                ...    
            } else {
                ...
            }
        })
    }

    func getLocation() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {            
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations  locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        locationLat = locValue.latitude
        locationLon = locValue.latitude
    }
```

I've only added part of the code.

What is the correct procedure to wait until the co-ordinates are received to call the sign up function?

The `requestWhenInUseAuthorisation()` is inside the `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: change the call method surely works

Comment: Call Sign Up Method Only when You receive the current location,you can use closures for that

Comment: If you are happy to target only ios9 and later,you can use `requestLocation` https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation Otherwise you will need to write code in `didUpdateLocations` to check for an appropriate horizontal accuracy and then stop the location updates and complete the sign up. You will also need to provide appropriate code for when the user declines location permission or a location cannot be determined in a reasonable time

Comment: Notes taken @Paulw11 Thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**do like**

```
func signup() { 
        self.getLocation()

    }
```

call in here

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations  locations: [CLLocation]) {
          manager.stoptUpdatingLocation() // initialy stop updation
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate

        locationLat = locValue.latitude
        locationLon = locValue.latitude
         let point = PFGeoPoint(latitude:locationLat, longitude:locationLon)
        ...
        newUser[PF_USER_LOCATION] = point
        newUser.signUpInBackground(block: { (succeed, error) -> Void in

            if let errorInSignup = error {
                ...    
            } else {
                ...
                // call your main view
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.karthik Also, I had used the locationmanager.startUpdatingLocations(). This had been calling the delegate method multiple times. In should have replaced it with locationManager.requestLocation() in order to call it only once.

Comment: @Sowndharya - follow paul comments also once